# Having problems testing if an XML element exists

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, undefined, typeof

My script works fine when all of the elements I'm searching for are declared, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to test if an element exists or not.

```js
$placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data; // works if the element exists
```

I've tried testing out these lines of code:

```js
if (!($placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data in window)) //always true
{   
    alert("this doesn't exist");
    return $noValue;
}
else
    return $placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data;
```

Even if the element exists the if statement is true and executes the first block of code, if it doesn't exist it just generates an error saying that '$placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data' is undefined.

Next I tried this method:

```js
if (typeof $placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data == "undefined")
    {   
        alert("this doesn't exist");
        return $noValue;
    }
    else
        return $placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data;
```

This one actually works correctly if the element does exist, but still yields the same error as the one above it.

I tried making a try catch block, but I ran into the same problem of having to test if the element was undefined. D:<

All I need is a simple way to see if the element in question exists (i.e. if it is or isn't undefined.) Is there a method I'm not aware of or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT2: doing `$placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname).length`

works if the element isn't defined, but if it is an element like this:
    `<anElement></anElement>`

$placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname).length returns true, and it executes the statement when there is nothing in the element. Trying this test:

```js
if ($placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.data == null)
```

doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need to check if there are elements with a specific `tagname` in your `$placeHolder`. `getElementsByTagName` returns `NodeList` so you can check its `length`, this way:

```
if( $placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname).length > 0 )
```

Comment: YES! It worked! I should have known to check the array's length, another part of my code uses the length attribute...

Comment: what would I do if the element is there, but nothing is in it? Like <element></element>

Comment: @user2419560 in the similar way: `if( $placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname).length > 0 && $placeHolder.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].getElementsByTagName(childTagname).length >0 )`

Comment: I had to change the last condition so it had a ! in front of it, but other than that it worked. Would you mind explaining why it works?

Comment: @user2419560 each dom element / xml node has `getElementsByTagName` method. when you're trying to get node' children of specific type you have to check if there is at least one child with this type (`.length > 0`). after that you can get node child's children and so on..